# Is this expression valid?

Tags: c++, string, integer-overflow

I've met this code:

```
std::string str;
std::getline(std::cin, str);
std::string sub = str.substr(str.find('.') + 1);
```

first reaction was - this is invalid code. But after some thoughts it seems to be not so simple. So is it valid C++ expression (has predictable behavior)?

PS if it is not so clear question is mostly related to what will happen when '.' would not be found in `str`, but not limited to that, as there could be other issues.

Comment: Was it literally as above, with the `...` in there?!? Or is the question about the `substr` line?

Comment: It cannot be with `...` as it is invalid syntax.  it means that does not matter what str is initialized with. Yes question is about line with `substr`

Comment: *First reaction was - this is invalid code.* Why?

Comment: @Slava Well you were the one claiming you were surprised by obviously invalid code. The `substr` line doesn't look at all surprising to me. By using `...` instead of `"foobarbaz"`, you broke the cardinal rule and failed to provide an SSCCE.

Comment: Did you even bother looking up the documentation?  I don't understand why you felt the need to post this question.  [`std::string::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/), [`std::string::substr`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi question is what will happen when '.' not found

Comment: @Slava, then please go ahead and add this vital piece of information to your question.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi added that, thanks

Comment: @BrianRodriguez amount of answers and comments like if you can add 1 to `std::string::npos` shows that it is not obvious.

Comment: @Salvia Okay.  Please be more explicit in the future, you could have avoided a lot of negative votes.

Comment: @BrianRodriguez make it more explicit it would be controversial. For example if I put `.` into string people would say it is correct because `.` is there. I thought it is pretty obvious what that code suppose to show.

Comment: @Slava The responses you've gotten clearly shows otherwise.  If you had, instead of just puting `...`, given us a string without a `'.'`, your intention would have been crystal clear.  You can't expect everyone to think the way you do, it's better to just say as much as possible and shorten it up later.

Comment: @BrianRodriguez missing . is only one issue. There could be more, for example . as a last symbol of the string.

Comment: @Slava No, that would have correct iterator behavior.  If it were at the end of the string, adding one to it would return the same thing as `str.end()`.  When two iterators are equal, that means it's an empty sequence, so you would get back an empty string.  The only invalid form of this code is when the period doesn't exist at all, but the answer shows that even that too is well-formed, though by a hard-to-reason technicality.  I would, personally, vote against using this in real-code.

Comment: @BrianRodriguez I understand that, point was issue in this code could be not only related to missing '.' so I did not want to ask "will it work fine when . is missing" but could be there any issues on valid input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str.find('.')` returns the index of the first occurrence of the character in your string. `substr` with one argument returns the suffix of the string starting at the given index. So what the line does is it returns the tail of the string starting right after the first dot. So if `str` is `"hello.good.bye"`, `sub` will be `good.bye`.

However, there **is** potentially a problem with the code if the string does not in fact contain any dots. It will return the whole string. This may or may not be intended. This happens because if there is no dot, `find` will return `npos`, which is the largest number `std::string::size_type` can hold. Add `1` to it, and you will get 0 (that's how unsigned types behave, modulo 2<sup>n</sup>).

So the code always has predictable behavior.

Comment: If there is no `'.'`, you will get `npos`, which I don't think you can legally `+1` to.

Comment: @BoBTFish Isn't unsigned integer overflow defined in the standard?

Comment: @NathanOliver Correct. I had to think about it a few seconds longer.

Comment: @BoBTFish I was still finishing up my answer.

Answer (score 2):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos it seems that `std::string::npos = -1;`.  That value is returned when the `find` is unsuccessful. In that case, the `str.substr(0)` will return the entire string.

It would seem it is valid and predictable code.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking about what happens if `.` is not found, you don't have to worry. `std::string::find` then returns [`std::string::npos`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/npos), which is defined to be `-1` by the standard, which, after adding `1` overflows and makes the argument `0`:

```
std::string sub = str.substr(0);
```

which gives you the whole string. I don't know if that's the desired behavior, but it's certainly not undefined behavior.

Comment: npos cannot be -1 it has type `size_t`

Comment: It overflows to `0` either way, no?

Comment: @Slava the standard defines `npos` as `size_type npos = -1`.

Comment: @Slava `-1` as an unsigned is well defined as the additive inverse of `1`.  So in an unsigned type `-1` isn't negative but it is the value to which adding `1` will give you `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, in this specific case--because the string that contains "...does not matter..." actually does--the `find()` call is not going to find what it is looking for and so will return `std::string::npos`.  You then add 1 to this.

npos is of type `std::string::size_type`, which is generally `size_t`, which is usually an unsigned integer of some sort.

`npos` is defined as the greatest possible value for `size_type`.

With `size_type` being unsigned adding 1  to the greatest possible value creates 0.

So you're calling `std::string::substr(0)`.  What does this do?  It creates a copy of the whole string you called it on because `substr` takes a starting position and length (defaulting to `npos`, or "all the way to the end").

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see it is valid though it isn't particularly readable.

If `str` is empty then the `find()` method will return `std::string::npos`. This is equivalent to the largest `unsigned int` representable by `std::size_type`. By adding 1 to this you're causing an integer overflow and it will wrap around to 0. This means the `substr()` method is attempting to create a string using chars from position 0 till the end of the string. If `str` is empty then `sub` is also empty.